# Level 10 with droids

Tags: untrusted

In Untrusted, how can I pass the many attack and defense droids?

I've tried going down, but they get stuck; I tried sending them right, but they cover the exit.

[image]

Comment: Alternative approach: override `onCollision` so you can just walk right through the enemies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the red drones, give the following:

```
if(me.getY()>11)
    me.move('up');
else if(me.getX()>0)
    me.move('left');
```

The yellow drones can be given this:

```
me.moveToward('block');
```

Give the green drones this code:

```
if(me.getY()>11)
    me.move('up');
else if(me.getX()<map.getWidth()-1)
    me.move('right');
```

Just move right and the red and green drones will line up and move towards the top corners.

[image: Line 'em up]

Answer (score 3):

Something easy and simple.

Red Drones

```
  me.move('left');
  map.placeObject(12, 12, 'block');
```

Yellow and Green Drones

```
  me.move('left');
```

[image: My solution]

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by simply giving every single drone a random chance to go either 'up' or 'right'.

> ```
> var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1
> switch(z){
> case(1):
>   me.move('up');
>   break;
> case(2):
>   me.move('right');
>   break;
> }
> ```

Copy and paste to all three drones.

Answer (score 2):

I found a cooler way, take a look:
red:

`moveToward(me, 'dummy1');`

nothing at all in yellow

green:

```
        moveToward(me, 'dummy2');
    }
});
map.defineObject('dummy1', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': 'R',
    'color': 'white',
    'behavior': function (me) {
            }
});

map.defineObject('dummy2', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': '+',
    'color': 'white',
    'behavior': function (me) {
            }
});

map.placeObject(2, 13, 'dummy1');
map.placeObject(42, 11, 'dummy2');

map.defineObject('dummy3', {
    'type': 'dynamic',
    'symbol': '=',
    'color': 'white',
    'behavior': function (me) {`
```

I love my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Red Drones - keep moving the drones left and move your guy up one to avoid them as they approach.

```
if (me.getY()>11) {
  me.move('left');
}
```

Yellow Drones

```
Nothing, leave the yellow drones right where they are
```

Green Drones - keep moving the middle drone (y==12) to the right until it reaches (12,29) at which time you move it up one to get it out of way of the exit block

```
if (me.getY()==12) {
    if (me.getX()==29) {
         me.move('up');
     } else {
         me.move('right');
     }
}
```

[image]